# The image shrinks for tablet/mobile view

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using elementor in wordpress. I have insert some image. For dekstop view, the image not stretching but for tablet or mobile sizes the image shrinks. I cannot using custom css in elementor because you have to upgrade to pro. Is there any way to solve it? I want the actual image on dekstop appear exactly on mobile view. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom class to that section and add your own CSS in style.css, or elementor provides option different settings for mobile, tablet and desktop, you can use it.